# Can´t send form information

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, frontend

I have this form and I want to use its information to create a product using my API but it creates a empty object in my Mongo database. I´ve tried to enter pre defined information and it worked

```
<form id="form">
    <label>Nome do Produto</label> <br />
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required /><br />
    <label>Quantidade do Produto</label> <br />
    <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" required /><br />
    <label>Descricao</label><br /><br />
    <input type="textbox" id="description" name="description" required /><br />
    <button id="button">Criar</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </form>
  <script>
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          console.log("Test");
        }
      };

      xhttp.open("POST", `http://localhost:3000/apiv1/products`, true);

      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");

      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

      xhttp.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          name: req.body.name,
          description: req.body.description,
          quantity: req.body.quantity,
        })
      );
    });
```

Comment: `<button id="button">Criar</button>` is going to submit the form, thus causing a page transfer, and most likely either preventing the ajax request from happening, or terminating it before it finishes.

Comment: @Taplar how can I prevent that?

Comment: `<button type="button" id="button">Criar</button>`

Comment: @Taplar I tried to alter to {name:"test",description:"test",quantity"12" } and it stored that information in the DB

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Are you saying it is working now?

Comment: @Taplar no . I was writting that before your comment. I am going to test now if it works with your correction

Comment: @Taplar it didn´t work. It doesn´t even create an object in the DB

Comment: Ok, so my next question would be where does `req` come from?  I do not see it defined in your script.

Comment: my teacher said i have to send the body, that´s why. I tried req.parms too but it was no use

Comment: Sure, but if we are talking about logic in the browser, unless you define it yourself, or some library provides it to you, a variable `req` isn't going to just exist.  I would expect instead that for each of those form fields you would do a lookup for them, and get their value from the elements themselves.

Comment: @Taplar should I use query string? In my opinion it won´t work because there is no change in page

Comment: No I'm saying it should possibly follow a pattern of `name: document.getElementById('name').value,`

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. I´ve been all afternoon trying to fix it.Thank you